# Finding the coefficients of a sum

Tags: expression-manipulation

Suppose I have the following expression:

```
p[l_] := 1 + ((1 - q) p)/q Sum[(p (2 - p))^k/q^k, {k, 0, l}]
```

or

$p(\ell)=1+\dfrac{(1-q)p}{q}\sum_{k=0}^{k=\ell}\dfrac{p^k(2-p)^k}{q^k}$

Is there a way to get a general formula for the coefficients of its monomial expansion when $\ell$ is an arbitrary integer?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use the symbol `p` for two different things (function name and variable).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
SeriesCoefficient[p[l], {l, 0, n}] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  p \left(\frac{1}{q}-1\right)+1 & n=0 \\
>  -\frac{(p-2) p^2 (q-1) (\log (-(p-2) p)-\log (q))^n}{q n! \left(p^2-2 p+q\right)} & n>0
> \end{cases}$

Comment: With v12, if `p[l]` is full simplified prior to evaluating `SeriesCoefficient`, i.e., `SeriesCoefficient[p[l]//FullSimplify, {l, 0, n}]`, the result for `n == 0` is wrong. Do you know why this happens? This does not happen with v11.3.

Comment: I agree, I think it's worth reporting the issue to support!

Comment: Reported to Tech Support (CASE:4257770).

Answer (score 1):

Replacing $(2-p)^k$ by a multinomial and rearranging terms gives

```
pp[l_] := 1 + (1 - q)/q *
  Sum[(-1)^(s-k-1)*2^(2k+1-s)*Binomial[k, 2k+1-s] * p^s/q^k,
    {k, 0, l}, {s, k + 1, 2 k + 1}]
```

check:

```
Table[p[l] == pp[l], {l, 0, 10}] // FullSimplify
(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```